# Написание модуля на C с использованием вставок asm

Tags: c, linux, ассемблер, gcc

Здравствуйте, дамы и господа. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Писал модуль на языке С. Нужно было заменить время выполнения функций. Но функции ассемблеровские, например: mov. По глупости (скорее всего) решил, что код можно написать на Си и просто использовать asm вставку. Вот как это выглядит:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/msr.h>

static int __init test_init(void)
{
      unsigned long ini, end;
      rdtscl(ini);
      asm("mov 4,%eax\n\t" "add %eax,5\n\t");
      rdtscl(end);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "\nTSC: Elapsed time on mov(ticks): %li\n", end - ini);
      return 0;
}
module_init (test_init);
```

Компиляция проходит нормально, никаких ошибок нет. Но, когда я пытаюсь вставить модуль в ядро через insmod modulename.ko, то мне выдаётся Killed. И при проверке через lsmod, этот modulename там висит постоянно до перезагрузки. В графе Used стоит цифра 1. Соответственно, его не выгрузить. Собственно, вопрос заключается в следующем: что я делаю не так. Почему я не могу вставить модуль в ядро?

Пробовал написать данную часть кода на assembler и подключить через makefile. Но, скорее всего делал что-то не так, ассемблеровская функция не распознавалась и компилятор ругался на её вызов. Говорил, что функция задана неявно, вроде как.

Если это имеет значение, то сам makefile выглядит вот так:

```
obj-m += modulename.o
all:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell name -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell name -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: На мой взгляд программа вообще не имеет никакого смысла. Например, что это такое rdtscl(end);? Какой смысл в этом вызове, если аргумент не инициализирован?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, rdtscl() - это вовсе не вызов функции. Это макрос, который внутри себя получает адрес указанной переменной, и добавляет вставку на ассемблере, которая получает текущее время при помощи одноименной инструкции.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Это плохо. Это делает код запутанным.

Comment: Вообще, сам я программирую на С++ и C# под Windows. Просто появилась необходимость именно в этом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код на ассемблере, так, как он написан, делает не вполне то, что вы предполагаете.

`mov 4,%eax` кладет в `eax` содержимое памяти по адресу 4, а `add %eax,5` прибавляет `eax` к памяти по адресу 5. Обе операции весьма сомнительные, и скорее всего приводят к ошибке доступа в ядре, и Killed.

Предолагалось, вероятно, `mov $4,%eax` и `add $5,%eax`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Это помогло. Совсем не принял во внимание, что у AT&T сначала идёт источник, а потом пункт назначения